# some facts on max flow is surprising

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

in two following facts just the `second one` is **true**:

in every `max flow`, flow of `u` to `v` or `v` to `u` is zero.

there is **one** max flow **always**, such that flow `u` to `v` or `v` to `u` is zero.

> Why just the second fact is true and first one is false? I couldn't understand.

Comment: What are `u` and `v`? It sounds like these statements are referring to a particular weighted graph which we don't know about.

Comment: @Stef u and v is an arbitrary vertex (at least I think).

Comment: @Stef these (u and v) is supposed vertexes (arbitrary vertex).

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to construct max flows in a graph in which some of the flow is basically an independent cycle that has no bearing at all on the overall flow. For example, consider this graph:

```
A -2- B -1- C
|     |
2     2
|     |
D -2- E
```

Imagine we’re looking for a max flow from A to C. One possible way to do this is to do the following: place one unit of flow across the path A -> B -> C, then place one unit of flow counterclockwise around the cycle A -> D -> E -> B -> A. This is indeed a maximum flow, but there’s one unit of flow going each way on the edge from A to B. The flow around the cycle here is “useless” in the sense that none of that flow makes it to C, but it does obey all the other rules of a flow. That’s why the first claim is false.

However, any max flow can be converted into one that doesn’t have this property. For any edge where flow is being pushed both forwards and backwards, you can simply reduce the flow in both directions such that one direction has zero flow one way and whatever remaining flow going the other way. That’s why the second claim is true.